# Convert ASCII in SPSS

Tags: ascii, spss

I am trying to use the [Wilkinson](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aPzT0skGq3IgJ%3atspintl-test.com/products/tsp/benchmarks/wilk.rtf%20wilkinsin%20statistical%20test&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) test to compare several statistical software's. To read the ASCII files as in the first question I tried to save the tests as six separate .txt files with ANSI encoding. I also tried saving the tests as a .nfo file. The software (SPSS) should encode the file to ABCDE. In SPSS when I inserted the data and used a space delimiter than did File-> Read Data it just returns 1 2 3 4 5 "ONE". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full syntax for the reading of the file?

Answer (score 0):

For this example I used V18, and just going through the GUI I was able to import the file. Below is verbatim what the GUI produced (the only difference is I chose to use both spaces and comma's as delimiters.)

```
GET DATA
  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="C:\Users\Andy W\Desktop\test.txt"
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=" ,"
  /QUALIFIER='"'
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=1
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  V1 F5.3
  V2 F4.2
  V3 F4.3
  V4 F13.11
  V5 A4
  V6 A7
  V7 A3
  V8 F1.0
  V9 A1
  V10 F1.0
  V11 A4.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
```

I'm not quite sure why it produced the frivolous variables after V6, but otherwise it appears all is well. It interpreted `5D-0` as a string, but what is it supposed to interpret it as? You also can only choose one text qualifier, although in this example that does not hinder the strings being imported. Below is a screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Andy's SPSS code as the source. Unfortunately I do not have SPSS available to test it. Hope it works.

```
GET DATA
  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="C:\Users\Andy W\Desktop\test.txt"
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=" ,"
  /QUALIFIER='"'
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=1
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
    A F1
    B F1
    C F1
    D F1
    E F1
    NAME$ A7.
EXECUTE.
```

Do not know how to define both " and ' as QUALIFIER.

I tried to do the same task with PSPP (as I do not have SPSS available). The following code works nicely:

```
GET DATA
  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="/home/djhurio/temp/test.txt"
  /IMPORTCASES=ALL
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=" ,"
  /QUALIFIER="""'"
  /VARIABLES=
    A F1
    B F1
    C F1
    D F1
    E F1
    NAME$ A5.

list
  /var = all.
```

Got the following result:

```
A B C D E NAME$
- - - - - -----
1 2 3 4 5 ONE   
1 2 3 4 5 TWO   
1 2 3 4 5 THREE 
1 2 3 4 . FOUR  
1 2 3 4 5 FIVE  
1 2 3 4 5 SIX
```

Comment: It seams only one QUALIFIER can be specified in SPSS.